# how to fix "index 3 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 3" in one-hot encoding?

Tags: python, numpy

I was working on one-hot encoding using python. but there is some problem when i run one-hot-encoding

```
def one_hot_encode(labels):
    n_labels = len(labels)
    n_unique_labels = len(np.unique(labels))
    one_hot_encode = np.zeros((n_labels,n_unique_labels))
    one_hot_encode[np.arange(n_labels), labels] = 1
    return one_hot_encode
```

this is what i used to running one-hot endcode

and the data is like this...

`[3 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1]`

It occurs this error

> "index 3 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 3"

And i try another path...

change the part of code

```
one_hot_encode = np.zeros((n_labels,n_unique_labels+1))
```

This is running but it its not the 3 classes...
The result is like this

```
array([[0., 0., 0., 1.],
   [0., 0., 0., 1.],
   [0., 0., 0., 1.],
   [0., 0., 0., 1.],
   [0., 0., 0., 1.],
   [0., 0., 1., 0.],
   [0., 0., 1., 0.],
   [0., 0., 1., 0.],
   [0., 0., 1., 0.],
   [0., 0., 1., 0.],
   [0., 1., 0., 0.],
   [0., 1., 0., 0.],
   [0., 1., 0., 0.],
   [0., 1., 0., 0.],
   [0., 1., 0., 0.]])
```

how do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is raising from `[3 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1]`. You have 3 in your mapping `np.array` which means in some position you are trying to equal `index 3 to 1` but the problem is that *maximum index in your mapping array is* **2**.

```
def one_hot_encode(labels):
    n_labels = len(labels) # this will give 15
    n_unique_labels = len(np.unique(labels)) # this will give 3
    one_hot_encode = np.zeros((n_labels,n_unique_labels)) # will create 15x3 matrix
    one_hot_encode[np.arange(n_labels), labels] = 1 # error here you try to map index 3 to 1 which does not exist
    return one_hot_encode
```

Just simply change your mapping array from `[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]` to `[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`